# NodeJS Post multipart data (Image Upload)

Tags: image, post, upload

Hello I want to upload photo from my computer to https://generated.photos/anonymizer , I keep getting alert error in bodyz "Empty message body supplied with multipart form-data", Please help me with coding.
I want it to work like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3jyI.png

```
var request = require("request");
            var upfile = 'src/All/1.jpeg';
            fs.readFile(upfile, function(err, content){
                if(err){
                    console.error(err);
                }

                let url = "https://api.generated.photos/api/frontend/v1/images/similars";
                let data = "";

                data += "------WebKitFormBoundaryVIBbTfQEhARYeJqm" + "\r\n";
                data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"zeta\"\r\n";
                data += "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";
                let payload = Buffer.concat([
                    Buffer.from(data, "utf8"),
                    new Buffer(content, 'binary'),
                    Buffer.from('\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryVIBbTfQEhARYeJqm\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"per_page\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryVIBbTfQEhARYeJqm--', "utf8"),
                ]);
                let options = {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: url,
                    headers: {"Authorization": "API-Key Cph30qkLrdJDkjW-THCeyA", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36","Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryVIBbTfQEhARYeJqm" , "Content-Length": content.length },
                    body: payload,
                };
                request(options, function(error, response, bodyz) {



                    alert(bodyz);
    
        // after i make it work i will do
   // var response_data_parsed = JSON.parse(bodyz);
    // alert(response_data_parsed.images.thumb_url)
        
        
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: Is the variable name meant to be `bodyz` in the `request` callback and the `alert` function within?

Comment: bodyz is request response body, and const alert = require('alert');    @WillWalsh https://i.imgur.com/wKPJWfU.png , I have made somewhere mistake in Buffer data creating that's why i get this error. In Burp Suite if u change code it will give this same error https://i.imgur.com/QdAta21.png

Answer (score 0):

Remove
"Content-Length": content.length

And all working. Thanks anyway